# iMac 21.5” mid-2010 SATA Specification

Tags: imac, sata

Does the 21.5” mid-2010 iMac support the full 6 Gbps SATA III standard?

Answer (score 1):

Your systems SATA port is only SATA II (3.0 Gb/s) . So It Will Not Support . For Details :-

> https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/454939/Can+SATA+III+HDD+be+installed+on+mid+2010+iMac+Intel+21.5%22

Comment: But a SATA III drive is backward compatible.